# what is the easiest way to put two sets of records in SQL SERVER next to each other?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

i am writing following query to put two sets of records next to each other.

```
 WITH cte AS
  (SELECT SubSubsidaryAccountCode,
          sum(Debit) AS debit,
          sum(Credit) AS credit,
          ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY SubSubsidaryAccountCode
                             ORDER BY SubSubsidaryAccountCode) AS RN
   FROM TBLLedgerLevel4
   WHERE SubSubsidaryAccountCode LIKE '4%'
     OR SubSubsidaryAccountCode LIKE '5%'
   GROUP BY SubSubsidaryAccountCode ),
     cte2 AS
  (SELECT *
   FROM TBLLevel4)
SELECT a.SubSubsidaryAccountCode ,
       c.SubSubsidaryAccountName AS RevenuName ,
       sum(a.Debit) AS debit ,
       b.SubSubsidaryAccountCode AS SubsidaryAccount2 ,
       d.SubSubsidaryAccountName AS ExpenseName ,
       sum(b.Credit) AS credit
FROM cte a
JOIN cte2 c ON a.SubSubsidaryAccountCode = c.SubSubsidaryAccountCode
FULL JOIN cte b ON a.RN = b.RN
JOIN cte2 d ON b.SubSubsidaryAccountCode=d.SubSubsidaryAccountCode
WHERE a.SubSubsidaryAccountCode LIKE '4%'
  AND b.SubSubsidaryAccountCode LIKE '5%'
GROUP BY a.SubSubsidaryAccountCode,
         b.SubSubsidaryAccountCode,
         c.SubSubsidaryAccountName,
         d.SubSubsidaryAccountName
```

**Output:**

```
 SubSubsidaryAccountCode    RevenuName  debit   SubsidaryAccount2   ExpenseName credit
     4-106-1001-10026        Cash Sale  52889    5-105-1005-10011   Rf Battles  18091289
     4-108-1012-10037        New Sale1  1000     5-105-1005-10011   Rf Battles  18091289
```

The above output contains records against two Accounting codes that starts with 4 and 5 .Now the records against accounting code that are starting with accounting code like 4 are populated and are according to desired results but the 2nd row of record starting with accounting code 5 is not populated and must have null value in it.Please help me out to solve this problem.

Comment: you filter for `a.SubSubsidaryAccountCode LIKE '4%'` there cant be no rows with acc code like 5

Comment: it would be better if you provide sqlfiddle for your tables with data

Comment: @khurram i have provided each and every thing to describe my problem there is nothing left to tell so plz rply with an answer!

Comment: @Aツ i didn't get your point . what your are trying to say ?

Comment: could you please provide your expected output?

Comment: i have already shown my output in my question

Comment: and i wall i want is in the second row there should be only record for account that is starting with 4 the columns starting with subSidaryAccount2 second row must have null value!

Comment: @sheikhmuzammil You said that `2nd row of record starting with accounting code 5 is not populated and must have null value in it`
would you like to tell why you are supposing null values what is the logic behind ...We are not aware of your tables hierarchy that is the reason you did not find your answer

Comment: @KhurramAli Because i am fetching this record from one table that has values against these account code. Now after summing up amounts of same accounting code there are two rows for account code that start with 4 just like i mention in output contains cash sale and new sale1 against code that start with 4 but the code that start with 5 has only one record Rf battle but it is showing as twice so that's why the 2nd row of accounting code starting with 5 should have null value!

Comment: @sheikhmuzammil join my room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73262/sql-c

Comment: @KhurramAli   don't have enough reputation to join

Comment: @sheikhmuzammil try again now have 20 reputations to join

Comment: yes my reputation is 21 now but chat is  still not working :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73273/discussion-between-sheikh-muzammil-and-khurram-ali).